# GLSL mat cannot access with variable index?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I declare a mat(3*3) in shader, based on OpenGL ES2.0 on Android.
Then I want to use two loops to go through this mat

```
    mat3 GX = mat3( -1.0, 0.0, 1.0,
                -2.0, 0.0, 2.0,
                -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 );
  for(int I=-1; I<=1; I = I + 1)
    {
        for(int J=-1; J<=1; J = J + 1)
        {
           GX[I+1][J+1]; // cannot get the value here!!!
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just pasted this code 'as is' in my shader program, shader compiles correctly (in the iPhone simulator). What is the error? GX[I+1][J+1]; does nothing btw which is the confusing part to me, your code iterates the matrix, evaluates each element, and does nothing with it???

Answer (score 1):

Implementations of ES 2.0 are not required to support this use of array indices. In section "Appendix A: Limitations for ES 2.0" of the spec document, under "Variables", it says:

> Support for indexing with a constant-index-expression is mandated.
>   Support for indexing with other values is not mandated.